# Bash sed in loop

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use the follow to substitute the tab with comma in several file:

```
#!/bin/sh 
for i in *output_*.txt  
do   
sed 's/ /;/g' $i > $i 
done
```

But it is not working because in the output file I still have the tab delimiter. It just work when I'm using it on a single file without the for loop.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you inserting the tab character?  bash takes tab as a completion, which can cause issues.  Most sed's support \t for a tab, else `tab=$'\t'` then `sed "s/$tab/;/g" $i > $i`

Comment: it looks like you're substituting space for semicolon. try using `sed -i 's/\t/,/g' $i`. `-i` option means *in place*.

Comment: Try using the -i flag of sed that enables in-place substitution.

Comment: Be careful; I hope you've got copies of your data, because 'sed ... $i > $i' has the shell create an empty output file called `$i` before `sed` gets to read it.  You cannot edit a file in situ like that.  If you have GNU `sed`, there's a `-i` option.  Otherwise, write to a temporary file and then copy the temporary over the original when done (or move the temporary).

Comment: You seem to be replacing a space (or tab) with a semi-colon, too, but that could just be a confusing layout.

Comment: So there is no way to sub space with comma in a file and write the result on the same file. I don't want to create new files. Did I get this write?.

Comment: Ok here it is my solution. I don't know if it is elegant or not but it works. `for i in *output_*.txt  
do   
sed 's/ /;/g' $i > "u3"$i; 
cp "u3"$i $i; 
rm $i; 
done`

Answer (score 3):

Several things are wrong. Unqouted variables and output redirection into same file. Loop is also not needed.

Try: 
    `sed -i 's/ /;/g' *output_*.txt`

Comment: I have different file with different name so just    sed -i 's/ /;/g' output_.txt will not work.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I need to write to file. I was doing this by overwriting the original file. But has someone point out sed first create an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

The correct script you need is as follows:

```
find . -name '*output_*.txt' | while read FILENAME; do
    (sed -e "s/\\t/;/g" <${FILENAME} >${FILENAME%.txt}.tmp) && (mv ${FILENAME%.txt}.tmp ${FILENAME});
done
```

This script has several important features:

1. It finds all files called `*output_*.txt` in the current directory and all subdirectories. If you *do not* want to recurse into subdirectories, then use:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*output_*.txt' | while read FILENAME; do
   ```

   as the first line.
2. It **does not overwrite** your original input file if `sed` encounters an error. `sed` generates its output to a temporary file (`<filename>.tmp`) and it only replaces the original file if it is successful.
3. As pointed out by other posters, the *tab character* is represented by `\t` in `sed` scripts.

An example transformation performed by this script is as follows (the sequence `<tab>` represents a *tab* character):

Input:

```
    <tab><tab><tab><tab><tab>line 1<tab><tab>
    <tab><tab><tab>line 2<tab><tab>
    <tab><tab>line 3<tab><tab>
    <tab><tab><tab>line 4<tab><tab>
    <tab><tab><tab><tab><tab>line<tab><tab> 5
```

Output:

```
    ;;;;line 1;;
    ;;;line 2;;
    ;;line 3;;
    ;;;line 4;;
    ;;;;;line;; 5
```